# Möbius transformation with exactly one fixed point is conjugate to the translation $z \to z+1$

Tags: complex-analysis, group-theory, complex-numbers, mobius-transformation, fixed-points

Here is the problem:

> Show that if a Möbius transformation $f$ has exactly one fixed point, then it is conjugate to the translation $z \to z+1$.

My work so far:

Let $a$ be the fixed point of $f$ and let $f(z) = \frac{Az+B}{Cz+D}$.
It suffices to show that there is a Möbius transformation $h$ such that $h(f(z))=h(z)+1$.  The author suggests we consider a Moebius transformation that maps the fixed point to $ \infty$ ( why is this?). So I try $h(z) = \frac{1}{z-a}$. We need to then check that:

$h(f(z))= \frac{1}{\frac{Az+B}{Cz+D}-a}= h(z)+1 =\frac{1}{z-a}+1.$ Noting that $f(a)=a \implies \frac{Aa+B}{Ca+D}=a \implies a(A-Ca)=Da-B$ the lhs becomes,

$ h(f(z))= \frac{C}{A-aC}(\frac{a+\frac{D}{C}}{z-a}+1)$, after some algebra.

But I do not see how this is equal to $h(z)+1$. Do I have to choose a different $h$ or I am doing something wrong here? Also why are we mapping the fixed point to infinity in the first place? Many thanks!

Comment: Can you show a Mobius transformation fixing $\infty$ has the form $z\mapsto az+b$?

Comment: Yes, that's fine... if $f$ fixes infinity then the denominator is a constant, so the transformation is affine, as required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ has exactly one fixed point $a \in \Bbb C$ and $h(z) = 1/(z-a)$ then 
$$
 T = h \circ f \circ h^{-1}
$$
is a Möbiustransformation with $\infty$ as the only fixed point. Show that necessarily 
$$
 T(z) = z + b 
$$
for some $b \in \Bbb C$, $b \ne 0$, and finally use
$$
 z + b = (\frac zb + 1) \cdot b
$$

Your approach was not successful because you used $f(a) = a$, but not that $a$ is the *only* fixed point of $f$.

Comment: So no algebra needed! Nice, thank you!

Comment: Surely $T(z)=az+b$ is also possible, no?Actually, this probably doesn't matter...

Comment: @user: If $T(z)=az+b$ with $a \ne 1$ then $T$ has *another fixed point* at $b/(1-a)$, in addition to the fixed point at infinity.

Comment: Ah right! Thank you!

Comment: So my reasoning in the comment section of my post is correct, except for this (important) detail?

Comment: @user: Yes. If $T$ fixes infinity then it is affine. If infinity is the *only* fixed point of $T$ then $T$ is a translation.

Comment: Perfect. All understood then!